# Can Google decide to demote or promote a particular company in search results?

Tags: google-search

Let's say Google has fight with Apple, can Google decide to do so that when you search for "Apple" in Google, you won't find any references to the Apple company? Or, can you pay Google to make your website higher in the search results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Google's Search engine, and they can do with it what they want. They *could* set it up so that no Apple results appear in the search, but that would certainly make their search engine less valuable. If their search engine is less valuable, then fewer people will use it, resulting in lower revenue as there will be fewer ads served. Google won't do that.

And no, you can't pay Google to get better ranking in their search results. That's one of their main "selling points". (Search Engines before Google did do that, and as a result nobody trusted the results.) Paid links are fairly clearly delineated from the regular crawled content.

Comment: Oh awesome, by the way, I've gotten that idea because I've heard somewhere that there's actually a law that prohibits from Google degrading other companies, is that true?

Comment: @andrey: No, although Google is having some trouble in Europe because some feel that Google unfairly advantages its properties. That's far beyond the scope of this site, however.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the helpful answer :).